# After saving html file, jqueryUI resizable doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

My page has a button. After clicking it, a box is added to an area on the page. This box is made to be draggable and resizable. Everything works.
Then, I save my html page to my computer. I open the saved file. But now, although the box is still draggable, IT IS NO LONGER RESIZABLE. That's the problem. Why does that happen? How do I fix it?

I would give a jsfiddle, but then you wouldn't be able to replicate the problem (which involves saving the web file) so I just posted the code below.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <button id="add">ADD</button>   
    <div id="area"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#area {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Javascript/jQuery/jQueryUI:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.box').draggable().resizable();

    $('#add').click(function(){
        var box = $('<div />')
            .addClass('box')
            .draggable()
            .resizable();
        box.appendTo($('#area'));
    });

});
```

At first, the resizable() was only binded to the box when the box was added to the area, but once the page is saved, the elements seem to lose all their bindings. That's why I threw in that first line (in the JS) which binds the draggable and resizable first thing on ready. This makes it draggable even after reopening a saved file, and it should make it resizable as well, but it doesn't.

I hope my problem here is clearly explained, thanks for any help you can give me.
I'm using Chrome. I've tried jquery 1.10.2 and jquery 2.0.0. I've also tried jquery-ui-1.10.3 and jquery-ui 1.10.4, both with the smoothness theme.

Comment: if you were able to fix it then the explanation should go in an answer, save others time trying to help and it makes the answer easy to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added one line to the script (the first line) which makes it work now. See the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.box').empty().removeClass('ui-resizable ui-draggable');
    $('.box').draggable().resizable();

    $('#add').click(function(){
        var box = $('<div />')
                .addClass('box')
                .draggable()
                .resizable();
        box.appendTo($('#area'));
    });

});
```

I'm practically resetting the resizable and draggable effects.
When you make something resizable, it throws a bunch of divs next to it, and then wraps all that in a div. In this case, since my selector was already a div, instead of wrapping, it threw a bunch of divs INTO it ('.box'), and then added the classes to IT ('.box'). The line I wrote undoes that, and redoes it.

To "reset" that, I empty out all ".box"es and remove the classes. Then I make them resizable and draggable again.

The reason draggable worked before was because, it is simply a matter of whether the element has the class "ui-draggable", whereas the resizable adds other elements to the mix. When a page is saved, it keeps those elements and those classes. Now when it is reloaded, it tries to add the classes again, but it sees that it doesn't need to, so it doesn't. (draggable is fine). But for resizable, it'll add the elements again, regardless of the fact that they're there already. This doubling probably hinders the resizable somehow...